# Data type conversion in MD5 either SSIS or C#

Tags: c#, ssis, amazon-redshift, md5, informatica

I am converting some packages from Informatica to SSIS and the source is MySQL and the destination is AWS Redshift 
Problem is that the informatica has an MD5 expression containing char, varchar, `MMDDYY` and `MMDDYY HHMMSS` as part of the expression for hashing which is used for incremental load

My problem is that when I write a C# script I am unable to convert the dates properly.

And I am unable to use an OLEDB or Execute SQL task as it is isn't compatible with Redshift

So am stuck. Any tip will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to parse `MMDDYY HHMMSS` and `MMDDYY` date values to date time using c#, you can simply use `DateTime.ParseExact()` function to do that. Assuming the `outColumn` is the output column of type `DT_DATE`:

```
Row.outColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.DateColumn,"MMddyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or

```
Row.outColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.DateColumn,"MMddyy HHmmss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or you can define an array of string that contains all formats and use it within this function:

```
string[] formats = {"MMddyy","MMddyy HHmmss"};
Row.outColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.DateColumn,formats,System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

### Update 1

Based on your comments, you need to use:

```
Row.DateColumn.ToString("MMddyy")
```

Comment: Thanks Hadi,  The Hasbytes ('MD5' ... function takes in only String values.  So I have convert the Date and DateTime input values into string.  I tried Datetime.ToString and DateValue.ToString.  But does not give me the desired result.  I am a bit weak in C#.  Is there any way that I can convert the value that comes in as datetime (MMDDYY HHMMSS)is restricted to a date (MMDDYY) and then is converted to String

Comment: @user11911434 use `Datetime.ToString("MMddyy")`